# Function template deduction l-value reference and universal reference

Tags: c++, c++11, function-templates, forwarding-reference, template-argument-deduction

Let's say I have the function `copy`:

```
template <typename Buf>
void copy(
    Buf&& input_buffer,
    Buf& output_buffer) 
{}
```

In which `input_buffer` is a universal reference and `output_buffer` is an l-value reference.

`Reference collapsing rules` make sure `input_buffer` is indeed, regardless of the deduced type of `Buf`, an universal reference and `output_buffer` is indeed an l-value reference.

However, I wonder how type `Buf` is deduced here.

I found out that `copy` is passed an r-value as `input_buffer`, (and an l-value as `output_buffer`, obviously) `Buf` is a non-reference type.

If I were to pass two l-values however, the program does not compile:

```
int i = 4;
int j = 6;

_copy(i, j);
```

I would expect the compiler to deduce `Buf` to `int&`. Following the reference collapsing rules, I would expect `input_buffer` to become an l-value reference, that is, `& + && -> &`, and `output_buffer` to become an l-value reference too; `& + & -> &`.

So the question is: Why doesn't this code compile?

(Note: I am not necessarily asking for a solution to the problem, but for an explanation.)

If I need to elaborate, feel free to ask.

EDIT:
if call: `copy(i, j);`
GNU GCC Compiler gives:
error: no matching function for call to 'copy(int&, int&)'
note: candidate: template  void copy(Buf&&, buf&)
note:    template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:    deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Buf' ('int&' and 'int')

if call: 
`copy<int&>(i, j);`
OK.

Comment: I don't know if Buf can be deduced as both a universal reference and a normal reference simultaneously. Make the function templated on two types does fix the problem, but is more constrained than you probably want. BTW, it would be good to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the compiler error that you receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Type deduction for *forwarding reference*:

```
template<class T>
void f(T&& val) {}
```

[a.1] when you pass Lvalue `T` is deduced to be `T&`. So you have

```
void f(T& && ){} -after reference collapsing-> void f(T&){}
```

[a.2] when you pass Rvalue `T` is deduced to be `T`. So you have

```
void f(T&& ) {}
```

b) Type deduction for reference except *forwarding reference*:

```
template<class T>
void f(T& param){}
```

when you pass Lvalue, `T` is deduced to be `T`. `param` has type `T&` but template argument is `T`, not `T&`.

So below code compiles

```
int i = 10;
copy(20,i);
```

because type deduction for first argument returns `Buf==int` since you passed 20 Rvalue.
And result of deduction for second argument also returns `Buf==int`. So in both
cases `Buf` is the same, code compiles.

Code which doesn't compile:

```
int i=1;
int j=2;
copy(i,j);
```

What is deduced type for first argument? You are passing L-value, so `Buf` is `int&`.
Second deduction returns `Buf==int`. These two deduced types are not the same, that is why 
code doesn't compile.