# Function template overloading with reference collapsing

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, function-templates

In addition to this question, [Function template deduction l-value reference and universal reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175851/function-template-deduction-l-value-reference-and-universal-reference), I have another question. Note you do not have to read this post to understand this, but it might be helpful. This post does by the way not show the ideal solution to the problem I believe, but that's not the point.

```
template <typename Buf>
void copy (
    Buf&& input_buffer,
    Buf& output_buffer)
{} // 1)

template <typename Buf>
void copy (
    Buf& input_buffer, 
    Buf& output_buffer)
{} // 2)

...

int i = 4;
int j = 6;

copy<int&>(i, j); // copy taking two l-values; calls second instance.
```

I would expect if I were to call `copy<int&>(i,j)`,  the first instance of `copy` would be called. Type `Buf` is specified, so does not require to be deduced. `Reference collision rules` result in both `input_buffer` and `output_buffer` being l-value references. The first instance is the first valid function.

It is not a template specialization, so it does also surprise me that the compiler actually chooses either, in stead of giving an error.

The second instance of `copy` may appear more specified, but if `Buf` is `int&` the first instance also expects two l-value references.

So, the question is, why is the second instance preferred? I would expect that the compiler first actually creates the function, by substituting the template argument. Then, it turns out that `Buf&& input_buffer` in instance one is equal to `Buf&`.

Feel free to ask if I need to elaborate.

Comment: See [overload_resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) and [Function_template_overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading).

Comment: I think it is usually a mistake to design a code around the idea of calling explicitly specializations of template functions when they can be otherwise deduced. If nothing else rethink if the function is named well. (a "buffer" is not something that I would think as copyable in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both templates (1) and (2) instantiate to the same signature, so which one is called depends on the partial ordering rules. Partial ordering operates on the template declarations, not on their specializations produced by implicit instantiation nor on their explicit specializations.

According to the partial ordering rules, we determine whether (1) is at least as general as (2), and whether (2) is at least as general as (1). If the answers are respectively "yes" and "no", then (2) is more specialized and is chosen.

To determine whether (1) is at least as general as (2), we synthesize some unique type for `Buf` and substitute it into the signature of (2), then try to deduce the arguments of (1) from the hypothetical specialization so generated. The idea is that if this works for a unique type, then it must also work for every other type.

Indeed, if we substitute `Buf` = `Unique` in (2), we get

```
void copy (Unique& input_buffer, Unique& output_buffer)
```

This results in `Buf` being deduced as `Unique&` in (1) (this works because of the reference-collapsing rules).

If we do it the other way around, substituting `Buf = Unique` into (1), this results in the signature

```
void copy (Unique&& input_buffer, Unique& output_buffer)
```

Now we try to deduce `Buf` in (2) from this---but of course it doesn't work, because (2) can only ever generate specializations where both parameters are lvalue references.